# How can I send Pusher broadcast and listen via Echo in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, echo, pusher

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve... I want to use Pusher for broadcasting reservation dates and times. But somehow I'm not able to receive any. Maybe the issue is with sending but I've been searching through the internet for hours unable to find anything that would solve my problem...
Here is my Event:

```
class ReservationMade extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Date of the reservation
     *
     * @var Date
     */
    public $date;

    /**
     * Time of the reservation
     *
     * @var Time
     */
    public $time;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($date, $time)
    {
        
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->time = $time;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['pneupoint1'];
    }
    
}
```

Here a controller function:

```
protected function prereserveDate(Request $request){
        broadcast(new ReservationMade($request['date'], $request['time']))->toOthers();
        return  response()->json([
            'reserved' => true
        ]);
    }
```

Echo thing:

```
Echo.channel('pneupoint1').listen('ReservationMade', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Broadcasting routes:

```
Broadcast::channel('pneupoint1',pneupoint1::class);
```

Comment: can you please add your route here?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid which routes?

Comment: which route file containing your broadcasting routes. by default it's channels.php

Comment: @EmtiazZahid okay now included